# ScreenOrientation in IONIC 7 and Capacitor 5.2.3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic7

I have Ionic 7.1.1 and Capacitor 5.2.3, and I can't find on the official page ***how to install the screen-orientation plugin***. Also, I see an end-of-life notice on the page. I don't quite understand what to do. Is it possible to obtain it without using Cordova or Ionic Enterprise? In case I have to use Cordova, which I don't want to, do I just need to add the plugin? Or do I also need to install Cordova globally as before? Thank you very much

Comment: did you try https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/screen-orientation ? or followed instructions in https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/screen-orientation ?